# Hide "Please Wait" during Windows 8.1 Shutdown

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown, windows-embedded-8

I'm trying to find out how (if?) to hide the "Please Wait" screen during a shutdown/reboot of Windows 8.1.

Being able to show a black screen or custom screen would be ideal.

Specifically, this screen:
[image: Please Wait Screen]

In case it matters, I'm looking to implement this solution on a Windows 8.1 Embedded machine.

Comment: I don't have a Windows 8.1 Embedded system to test it with, but try running the following command from an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-8): `bcdedit /set {globalsettings} custom:16000068 true` This should disable messages such as "Please wait", "Updating registry", etc. If you also want to disable the spinning animation, run this command: `bcdedit /set {globalsettings} custom:16000069 true` Let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: Thanks andPI. These are pretty cool and do indeed change the boot up behavior, but unfortunately, turning off the "Please wait" on startup does not prevent the "Please wait" on shutdown =(

Answer (score 1):

I know a method to eliminate the text atleast.

navigate to C:\Windows\System32\en-US.

Find wininit.exe.mui and take ownership of it.

Make a copy of this on your desktop.

Then download "resource hacker" from here. http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Drag the copy you made into resource monitor, and you will see a list of files that are inside this file.

navigate to StringTable/63/1033

From there you will see the "please wait" text you were looking for.

Change that, click "compile script", and then click on file and save it.

This should bring up a new file on your desktop.

Simply drop that back into the en-US folder and click "replace" to replace the old one.

This is the way I've found to get rid of/ change the text. along with the "shutting down", "restart", and others.

Comment: thanks jAce. All of the steps worked as indicated, but unfortunately my screen still shows "Please wait" with the spinning dots. =(

Comment: @MattKlein Sorry I forgot I was going to respond to this. On a computer I did this to it didn't seem to work, but I left the settings modified anyways. I don't remember how much later (wasn't paying attention) but eventually (days later) it was using my modified texts. I don't know if it could be cached or something but maybe leave it changed and see if it eventually changes. Unless you've found another option by now. G'luck